# I want to find string length using JavaScript for loop without built-in function and while loop that I already completed

Tags: javascript

This is a JS while loop right code:

```
var str = length('I am a pro web developer.');
while( true ){
    if( str.charAt( len ) == '' ){
        break;
    }else{
        len++;
    }
}
console.log( len );
```

I want to find out the text length using for loop:

```
for( var len = 0; len > str.length(); len++ ){
    if( str.charAt( len ) == '' ){
        break;
    }
}
```

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Doesn't that seem strange to you searching for `str.length` with `for(.. len > str.length`?

Comment: `length` is a property of `str`, not a function, so the parentheses are unnecessary.

Comment: Even if you were allowed to use `str.length` here (which seems quite odd) your code would never reach the loop's body because the condition `len > str.length` is always false, when you initialize `len = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Original code:

```js
var str = 'I am a pro web developer.', len = 0;
while (true) {
  if (str.charAt(len) == '') {
    break;
  } else {
    len++;
  }
}
console.log(len);
```

Modified code:

```js
var str = 'I am a pro web developer.', len = 0;
for (; str.charAt(len) != ''; len++) ;
console.log(len);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Anton's answer, you can also simplify your first approach with the while loop

```
var str = `some string`;
var len = 0;
while (str.charAt(len) !== '')
  len++;
```

Or

```
var len = -1;
while (str.charAt(++len) !== '') ;
```

Or

```
var len = 0;
while ( str.charAt(len++) !== '') ;
len--;
```

For option 2 and 3 be sure to note the semicolon after the loop, making sure of the empty loop body